# Where to find F. Riesz collected papers?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

In Rota's *Ten lessons I wish I had been taught*, under the section *Publish the same result several times*, he mentions F. Riesz collected papers; any ideia on where to find them?

Comment: This is not a maths question. Not the correct forum for this.

Comment: It is a question about the publications of a mathematician.  Definitely the correct forum.

Comment: Try [here](https://www.worldcat.org/formats-editions/9800607)

Comment: I found faces: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Riesz/pictdisplay/

Comment: @RobertIsrael that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Marcel Riesz was Frederick (Frigyes) Riesz's younger brother. "Ten lessons I wish I had been taught" is a chapter of the book "[Indiscrete Thoughts](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-8176-4781-0_18)" in which both of their works and collected papers are mentioned and talked about together. It turns out, that one of the "Collected Papers" books that is mentioned [is a book that is possibly both of their combined works](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=FKb8wL3gUKIC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Frederick%20Riesz%27%20Collected%20Papers&ots=s6W1rzK_EE&sig=IPxhRE9KrHDOMVGfhYlSOE-e19s#v=onepage&q=Frederick%20Riesz%27%20Collected%20Papers&f=false). However, apparently some of the collected works in this book had been not included in certain editions, as [the editors chose not to include them](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81129185.pdf).

While it's almost difficult to locate a specific book by Frederick Riesz that's easily accessible, here is [a collection of his published works](https://openlibrary.org/authors/OL890337A/Frigyes_Riesz) as documented by the Open Library, of which possibly where the ones that were compounded into the one original big book in the past. In addition, WorldCat has [this list of his books](http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n84801566/).

Comment: Much of his work can be found either on the website of the journal ACTA (which he helped to create), or via the digitalization project of the french national library (he published several papers in the Comptes Rendus Math, whose eds. are available online). It is worth mentioning that his zbmath entry was also a very useful tool.